# Absolute Path and Relative Path issue in python

Tags: python, linux

How to remove path related problems in python?

For e.g. I have a module test.py inside a directory TEST

```
**test.py**
import os
file_path = os.getcwd() + '/../abc.txt'

f = open(file_path)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close

print lines
```

Now, when I execute the above program outside TEST directory, it gives me error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TEST/test.py", line 4, in ?
    f = open(file_path)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.txt'
```

how to resolve this kind of problem. Basically this is just a small example that I have given up.

I am dealing with a huge problem of this kind.

I am using existing packages, which needs to be run only from that directory where it exists, how to resolve such kind of problems, so that I can run the program from anywhere I want.

Or able to deal with the above example either running inside TEST directory or outside TEST directory.

Any help.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest thing is to change the current working directory to the one of the script file:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This may cause problems, however, if the script is also working with files in the original working directory.

Comment: how to use this utility.. It is giving me error.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: Before this degenerates into comedy: The markup is converting two underscores as __bold__ font. Use `__file__`.

Comment: `__file__` is not defined in in the interpreter. You should use it inside a script file.

Comment: Any other solution?? changing the directory might not be useful. I am using unittest module, to run few tests (regression suite) and inside each test, I am using few txt files, which is lying inside a directory in side regression_framework_directory, the path of which can be known through test case only. Now If i run the test case from outside, somewhere else, the txt files are not recognized. Any other solution please.?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking at the current working directory, and uses that as a basis for finding the files it needs. This is almost never a good idea, as you are now finding out.

The solution mentioned in the answer by Emil Vikström is a quickfix solution, but a more correct solution would be to not use current working directory as a startingpoint.

As mentioned in the other answer, `__file__` isn't available in the interpreter, but it's an excellent solution for your code.

Rewrite your second line to something like this:

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "abc.txt")
```

This will take the directory the current file is in, join it first with `..` and then with `abc.txt`, to create the path you want.

You should fix similar usage of `os.getcwd()` elsewhere in your code in the same way.